# Testing extending a list

Tags: python, performance

I am learning Python. I have a scenario in my current project to benchmark the following code snippet; by using refactoring to increase the performance. Upon deployment my code will be used on a larger scale.

I'm trying from my side and am also looking for suggestions/guidance from you all. Is there a way to make this code much faster and cleaner with less line of code?

```
def test(x1, x2):
    if x2 is None:
        return
    elif len(x2) == 1:
        x1.append(x2)
        return
    else:
        for i in range(len(x2)):
            x1.append(x2[i])
    return

l = ['tt', 'yy', 'pp']
test(l, None)
print (l)


test(l, ['hello'])
print(l)

test(l, ['hello', 'world'])
print(l)
```

Comment: Could you attempt to rewrite your question a bit? I don't really understand what it is that you want help with. I also don't understand what the purpose of your function is.

What performance are you speaking of (memory usage or speed), and how is it relevant to this function? Do you only want suggestions on how to make the algorithm faster?

Comment: Your code looks very much like an example. Please note that [codereview.se] is the exact opposite of [so] in that regard. On [so], you should *not* post your actual code, you should instead construct a *minimal reproducible example*. Here on [codereview.se], however, you should *not* post incomplete, hypothetical, or example code, but instead your real-world, actual, working code.

Comment: Also, please explain a bit more, what does your code do and what do you want from us? Remember: in a "real world" code review, the code review would be held with a specific purpose (improving throughput, reducing memory usage, find security holes, improve readability, etc.) and you would be in the room with us, walking us through your code line-by-line explaining every choice, every variable, every function. On this website, all we have is your question, so you need to make sure that all the information that we would *normally* get during the code review session is part of the question.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. As such I have rolled back your latest edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `extend()` instead of `append()` to add a list to another list, and use the fact that `None` and empty lists compare as `False`, while a non-empty list compares as `True`, and omit the redundant `return` statement:

```
def test(x1, x2):
    if x2:
        x1.extend(x2)
```

As for reducing the number of print statements, prepare a list or tuple with your test cases, and handle them all in a single `for`-loop:

```
l = ['tt', 'yy', 'pp']
testcases = [
    None,
    ['hello'],
    ['hello', 'world']
]

for testcase in testcases:
    test(l, testcase)
    print(l)
```

Comment: This solution does not capture the `elif`-logic in the original code.

Comment: @GZ0 It looks like you're correct, in case of `x2` being a list of one element the original code appends a list instead of just the element. I assume that was not the intention though.

Comment: Thanks, @Sliepen. I was looking for a way to write the if-else statements using list comprehension.But didn't find anything in docs,

Comment: I was able to reduce the line of code. But the output is slightly different from the expected one. Updating my question as per the same

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code review.

- It is a good practice to add type hints to Python functions to specify parameter types. See [here](https://pythonpedia.com/en/tutorial/1766/type-hints) for more details. Note that type hints do not affect code execution. It is primarily for improving readability and helping IDEs look for potential bugs.
- When running code outside a function / class, it is a good practice to put the code inside a *main guard*. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) for more details.

  ```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
       ...
  ```
- The `for`-loop could be improved by using `+=`, which is equivalent to `extend` but shorter and faster.
- If the `None` input for `x2` happens rarely, one can use `try` ... `except` to catch the exception from `len(x2)` call in order to improve performance.

Following is my version of improved code. Since the types of input parameters are not explained, I will make the most general assumption that `x1` is a list and `x2` is a [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) or `None`.

```
from typing import Optional, List, Sequence

def test(x1: List, x2: Optional[Sequence]):
    try:
        if len(x2) == 1:
            x1.append(x2)
        else:
            x1 += x2
    except TypeError:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x1_input = ['tt', 'yy', 'pp']
    x2_inputs = [
        None,
        ['hello'],
        ['hello', 'world']
    ]

    for x2_input in x2_inputs:
        test(x1_input, x2_input)
        print(x1_input)
```

Output:

```
['tt', 'yy', 'pp']
['tt', 'yy', 'pp', ['hello']]
['tt', 'yy', 'pp', ['hello'], 'hello', 'world']
```

The function could be further shortened as follows:

```
def test(x1: List, x2: Optional[Sequence]):
    try:
        x1 += [x2] if len(x2) == 1 else x2
    except TypeError:
        pass
```